# Including Morphia for JSON-to-object mapping with JAX-RS+Jersey

Tags: java, mongodb, jersey, jax-rs, morphia

I'm setting up a REST route with JAX-RS+Jersey that consumes a JSON object.  This JSON object is special because one of the fields it contains is associated with a Morphia entity.  Is there a way to integrate Morphia's object-mapping with Jackson so that I can deserialize my object?

Example:

**Incoming JSON object in request body:**

```
{
    operation: "CREATE",
    document: {  // This object is a Morphia entity
        "name": "Bob"
        "age": 18
    }
}
```

should be mapped to

**POJO**:

```
public class JSONContainer {
    String operation;
    Document document; // This object is a Morphia entity
}
```

Comment: We use Morphia entities that are used as is in JAX-RS webservices. We needed only to configure a ContextResolver for the ObjectId class. Look at the 3 classes here: http://pastebin.com/UiW1auPJ

Comment: Do you have any errors? I don't see any problems. You should maybe post also the Document class defition.

Comment: I'm reading up on `ContextResolver` right now, but thanks a lot for the example you provided.  I'll see if this solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this github project titled "[morphia_jackson_polymorphism_example](https://github.com/denniskuczynski/morphia_jackson_polymorphism_example)"